# Do we need both [website] and [webpage]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Seems like one would be plenty:

- [website](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/website) (376)
- [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webpage) (61)

Comment: Aren't they technically two different things?

Comment: @SimonSheehan I'm sure one can define a difference, I doubt people do. And if they do, I doubt everyone shares the same definition. Yet, I think, both terms are so closely related, that a synonym would be appropriate.

Comment: I figure weboage would be to do with the actual pages, while website has to do with apache and SQL and such, the back ends

Comment: Oh, I was thinking in a completely different direction. Somewhat proving my point there...

Comment: I define a webpage as a single document on the web and a website as a collection of documents and associated services (think RSS).

Comment: @kotekzot That's more of the direction I was thinking in. I still think it's too ambiguous.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I'd be interested in hearing what you define them as. Having read through some of the questions tagged [webpage] and [website], I believe the distinction they provide is a useful one.

Comment: @kotekzot I would have thought that there is a slight difference to be made between a single `.html` page (webpage) and the content presented to you when you enter a given URL into your browser (website). But I would have assumed that this distinction varies between people.

Answer (score 3):

Similar as to what kotekzot said in the comments above, you can simply see it as:

> A webpage is a page on the web. A website is a site hosting pages on the web.

A webpage is not really ambiguous, you're watching one right now. A website can be interpreted somewhat ambiguous; in fact, look at the interesting different results Google provides us:

[image]

*Excuse me for no freehand circles and guiding text, there isn't much place for that.*

So, according to the dictionary a website is `a computer`. However, this is really incorrect as a computer can host multiple websites. If you also look at the other result, you get something more serious; but it's still loaded with stuffing words like `set` and `related`.

Putting that detail aside, we can at least assume two approaches:

- Hosting a website
- Browsing a website

Thus the [website](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/website) tag could be ambiguous because you can approach a website in (at least?) two ways.

From a slant look through that tag, I see questions about...

- ... uploading something to a website. *(browsing / hosting)*
- ... getting a website working. *(browsing)*
- ... website framework / system recommendations. *(hosting)*
- ... hosting a website in a certain way. *(hosting)*
- ... downloading / blocking / translation / ... *(browsing)*
- ... programming / design of a webiste. *(programmer / designer)*

So yeah, the tag is indeed used in a somewhat ambiguous way. However, it doesn't look bad to have this tag to me on the other hand; because introducing more tags like this wouldn't be a good idea.

Looking at [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webpage), these all seem indeed related to one webpage but I feel like they fit under the `getting a website working` type of questions (and similar) from the above list.

So, there is indeed the tricky question whether we would need this specific tag.

These are the options here:

1. **We merge** [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webpage) into [website](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/website).
2. **We keep them both**, making sure that [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webpage) is applied to questions regarding a single page. Because I think there are questions in [website](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/website) which could also be tagged [webpage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/webpage).
3. **We throw both of them away** and use better tags like for example [browsing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browsing) and [hosting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hosting).

However, this leaves me undecided. The first one breaks the usefulness of having them separated, the second could be kinda annoying to follow-up on and the third one takes categorization into account but would require thinking out in which tags we divide them in (and get rid of the off-topic stuff).

Thinking out the third point could lead to something, unless someone feels convinced by #1 or #2...

Comment: I don't see the usefulness in having them separated if the meaning is not clear. Therefore, 1 seems reasonable. I like 3, but people won't use "browsing" when they ask a question about a random "website" (i.e. that probably won't occur to them when tagging).

Comment: @slhck: If you set up a synonym from website to a more general tag like [tag:browsing] (just an example, perhaps better tags exist?) it would show up to them. #1 could be a solution as the separation isn't really that important, but is it on the other hand important to have one tag instead of two...

Comment: Yeah, but then *website → hosting* wouldn't exist too.

Comment: @slhck: If only http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags existed. :(

Comment: I think `[webpage]` is a valid tag, especially if you are talking about "save as webpage" or working with a web file (e.g. HTML). I think `[website]` is too vague and something like `[browsing]` or `[server]` would be better.